# Real time Dial Rotation Animation?

Tags: android, xml, animation

How can I create a dial/wheel that will rotate as it is touched and dragged? I've seen many tutorials and posts about animations that's a single click event, i.e. spin a circle onClick. I need a dial/wheel/circle that spins as I dial it with a finger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-rotating-dialer/) guide you step by step, how you can build a rotary dialer.